# Is there is analogue of npm variables (`npm_config_`) in yarn console scripts?

Tags: javascript, npm, terminal, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

You can use variables in your custom npm commands (example from https://www.twilio.com/blog/npm-scripts):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "demo": "echo \"Hello $npm_config_first $npm_config_last\""
  }
}
```

Is it possible with yarn?

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in solution in yarn, but I've found a way:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "demo0": "echo \"Hello\"",
    "demo": "node -e \"const args = process.argv.slice(1).reduce((acc, arg) => { const [key, value] = arg.split('='); acc[key] = value; return acc; }, {}); console.log('Hello', args.first, args.last);\""
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$ yarn demo0 Kevin Ross // everything after command will be considered as one argument
// interpreted as `echo "Hello" Kevin Ross`
Hello Kevin Ross // <<< output
```

Proper way:

```
$ yarn demo first=Kevin last=Ross
Hello Kevin Ross // <<< output
```